# Newton's method calculate the residual at fixed fixed slope

Tags: optimization

In Newton's method, if the residual delta x is iteratively updated ($X \leftarrow X + \Delta x$) at fixed slope, does it converge?

In newton's method, the estimation of X should be done iteratively. In each iteration the derivative (slope) of a function, the residual are calculated and used to update X. My question is if what will happen if we performed the derivative only one time.

More precisely, assume the following:
f(X)=A+B
my target is to estimate X

solution 1::

- outer loop calculate the slope of f(X)
- inner loop
- ----calculate A
- ----calculate B
- ----calculate delta x using f(x), A, B and the slope
- end inner loop
- X=X+ delta x
- end outer loop

solution 2::

- loop
- calculate the slope of f(X)
- calculate A
- calculate B
- calculate delta x using f(x), A, B and the slope
- X = X + delta x
- end loop

does the accuracy of X in both cases similar? and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "at fixed slope"?

Comment: In newton's method, the estimation of X should be done iteratively. In each iteration the derivative (slope) of a function, the residual are calculated and used to update X. My question is if what will happen if we performed the derivative only one time.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question.

The "normal" iterative scheme is $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ with a permanently updated *slope*.

You are asking about  $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_0)}$$ This was used a lot at a time (I knew that time) where computers did not exist and everything had to be done by hand. It works quite well provided $\cdots$ a few things. For sure, the convergence is slower than the "normal" method.

For illustration purposes, I selected $f(x)=e^{-x}-x$ starting using $x_0=1$. Below are given the iterates for the two cases.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{with update} & \text{without update}\\
 1 & 0.53788284273999024150 & 0.53788284273999024150 \\
 2 & 0.56698699140541323884 & 0.57158499872254489612 \\
 3 & 0.56714328598912294403 & 0.56650033488134524122 \\
 4 & 0.56714329040978386946 & 0.56723703773937297193 \\
 5 & 0.56714329040978387300 & 0.56712963572569512729 \\
 6 & 0.56714329040978387300 & 0.56714527957469274352 \\
 7 & 0.56714329040978387300 & 0.56714300064189749926 \\
 8 & 0.56714329040978387300 & 0.56714333262131691955 \\
 9 & 0.56714329040978387300 & 0.56714328426068052466 \\
 10 & 0.56714329040978387300 & 0.56714329130554557275
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder if the accuracy is changed between the two ways

Comment: @agwadElt. This was done using the same conditions. As you see, updating the derivative makes the solution reached at the fifth iteration while the no-update would take 24 iterations. However, if you want, you can update the derivative from time to time.

Comment: I think baby Rudin's proof of the inverse function theorem is based on this modified version of Newton's method.  In order to show existence of a point $x$ that satisfies $f(x) = y$, Rudin basically uses the modified Newton's method to find a solution (and he proves it converges to a solution using the contraction mapping principle).  Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. in my problem, there are other variables affects the calculations of delta x. Is the accuracy of final value X affected? and why?

Comment: @agwadElt. Are speaking about more than one equation and one unknown ? This would be a very different story. Please, clarify.

Comment: More precisely, do you think the results will be different between the following two solutions:

f(X)=A+B
solution 1-->
outer loop
calculate slope of f(X)
----inner loop
----calculate A
----calculate B
----calculate delta x
end inner loop
X=X+ delta x
end outer loop

solution 1-->

Comment: More precisely, do you think the results will be different between the following two solutions:

f(X)=A+B
solution 1::
outer loop
calculate slope of f(X)
----inner loop
----calculate A
----calculate B
----calculate delta x using f(x), A, B and the slope
end inner loop
X=X+ delta x
end outer loop

solution 2::
loop
calculate the slope of f(X)
calculate A
calculate B
calculate delta x using f(x), A, B and the slope
X=X+ delta x
end loop
does the accuracy of X in both cases similar? and why?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I have edited the original post to clarify this point, kindly see it.

Comment: @agwadElt. This looks more than dangerous since what you solve is $\Phi(x)=F(x)-A(x)-B(x)=0$

Comment: So, which solution is more accurate and why?

Comment: @agwadElt. What means accurate ? We need the solution and, to me, the second solution could lead to chaos. If, for any reason, you cannot express analytically $A'(x)$ and/or $B'(x)$ which could be (e.g.) implicit functions, use numerical derivatives to get $\Phi'(x)$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I mean the resulted X will be accurate in which solution. why do you think second solution could lead to a chaos?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. why does the first solution not lead to a chaos?